# VB.net regex character syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, vb.net

I can't get my sql query using regex to work in vb.net.

If I write

```
Dim localConnection As New MySqlConnection = ConnectionNew(DBName)
Dim da as MysqlDataAdapter
Dim ds as new DataSet
Dim rows as long

SQLstatement= "SELECT `col1` FROM `myTable` WHERE `col1` REGEXP '^[A-Z]BC$'" 

da = New MySqlDataAdapter(SQLstatement, localConnection)

rows = da.Fill(Ds)
```

It returns null, even though there is a cell containing "ABC". When I run it directly on the database, it returns the row correctly.

If I remove the [A-Z], it works fine in both circumstances.

Comment: REGEXP '^[A-Z]BC" - you miss regexp closing REGEXP '^[A-Z]BC'"

Comment: Maybe silly, but: Would one need another single quote, just after the BC? As in: "SELECT `col1` FROM `myTable` WHERE `col1` REGEXP '^[A-Z]BC'"

Comment: Sorry. Typo. I've edited it now.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to point to the problem in the vb.net code if there was any included in your question. Do you not think that, maybe, we might need to see some of it?

Comment: This doesn’t really seem to be related to VB … nothing in your query or the question pertains to VB.

Comment: Ok, I've added the surrounding VB now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that "binary strings" are involved?

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

> REGEXP is not case sensitive, except
>   when used with binary strings.

It also makes warnings about multi-byte characters.

> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in
>   byte-wise fashion, so they are not
>   multi-byte safe and may produce
>   unexpected results with multi-byte
>   character sets. In addition, these
>   operators compare characters by their
>   byte values and accented characters
>   may not compare as equal even if a
>   given collation treats them as equal.

Since VB.Net works in Unicode, is it possible that some sort of character-set or code-page mangling may be happening behind the scenes?